# Rails 5 sum and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My DB columns for model Taxline:
ID, RECEIPT, TAXID, BASE, AMOUNT

Let say I have db entries:

1,1,001,30$,3$

2,1,001,50$,5$

3,2,001,20$,2$

I want to show sum of amount for each receipt. Result should be:

1,8$

2,2$

My controller

```
    class TaxlinesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @taxlines = Taxline.group(:RECEIPT).sum(:AMOUNT)
  end

end
```

My View:

```
 <% @taxlines.each do |taxline| %>


        <td><%= taxline.RECEIPT %></td>
        <td><%= taxline.AMOUNT %></td>
```

But I get error undefined method `RECEIPT' for ["01a8fdd7-8eb6-44d0-a686-8010b9e30206", 145000.0]:Array

145000.0 and 01a8fdd7-8eb6-44d0-a686-8010b9e30206 refer to real vaules in db not to the example above. But it gives the idea.

App is built on existing db with column names uppercase.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Taxline.group(:RECEIPT).sum(:AMOUNT)` returns a Hash object rather than a set of Taxline instances like you are expecting. They keys are the grouped values (RECEIPT) and the values are the corresponding sums. Something like:

```
{ "01a8fdd7-8eb6-44d0-a686-8010b9e30206" => 145000.0, ... }
```

When you do `@taxlines.each` the Hash gets coerced into an Array.

With your current code you could simply change your view to this:

```
<% @taxlines.each do |receipt, amount| %>
    <td><%= receipt %></td>
    <td><%= amount %></td>
```