# Rails 5 Multiple Sums and Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144422/rails-5-sum-and-group) previously asked question.

My DB columns for model Taxline: ID, RECEIPT, TAXID, BASE, AMOUNT
With entries:
1,1,001,30$,3$

2,1,001,50$,5$

3,2,001,20$,2$

And then a second table with columns: TICKETID, TICKETNUMBER

My controller

```
class TaxlinesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @taxlines = Taxline.group(:RECEIPT).sum(:AMOUNT)
  end

end
```

My view

```
 <% @taxlines.each do |receipt, amount| %>

        <td><%= receipt %></td>
        <td><%= amount %></td>
 <% end %>
```

This works great to show a ticket for each row with corresponding total amount.

**Question 1**. What is the proper way to also show in view sum of BASE? I tried `.sum(:AMOUNT, :BASE) and .sum(:AMOUNT).sum(:BASE)` but they both don't work.

**Question 2**. If now I call in view for instance `<%= taxline.TAXID %>` I get an error. 
To solve this I tried to add in view `<% @taxlines.each do |receipt, amount, taxid| %> and <td><%= taxid %></td>. And in controller  @taxlines = Taxline.group(:RECEIPT).sum(:AMOUNT).select(:TAXID)`. But it shows a blank column.

**Question 3**. I want to show TICKETNAME value from TICKETS table.I have already set in Ticketline Model `belongs_to :ticket`. I assume that after solving question 1 I will be able to do ticketline.ticket.TICKETNAME.Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

Try this

```
@taxlines = Taxline.group(:RECEIPT).select("SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, SUM(BASE) AS BASE")
```

Question2:

To access `TAXID` you need to add this in group column.

```
@taxlines = Taxline.group(:RECEIPT, :TAXID).select("SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, SUM(BASE) AS BASE, TAXID")
```

Question 3:

To access the other table variables, you need to add join statement to the query and then you should group.

```
@taxlines = Taxline.joins(:ticket).group(:RECEIPT, :TAXID).select("SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, SUM(BASE) AS BASE, TAXID, TICKETNAME")
```

In the view side, try the below one.

```
<% @taxlines.each do |taxline| %>

        <td><%= taxline.AMOUNT %></td>
        <td><%= taxline.BASE %></td>
        <td><%= taxline.TAXID %></td>
        <td><%= taxline.TICKETNAME %></td>

 <% end %>
```

P.S: Not tried this.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: So, pls up vote my answer and mark it as correct answer :-)